# Set Python IDLE as Default Program to Open .py Files on Mac

Tags: mac, python

For some reason my computer decided to open my .py files with Atom, and that is now set to its default program. I tried changing the default program but I could not find Python IDLE on the list. Can someone help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on a .py file and hit `"Get Info"`. Scroll down to `"Open With"` and change to IDLE. Afterwards hit `"Change All"` to make it persist for all .py files.

If you simply hit `"Open With"` and try to make IDLE the default from that menu, it only makes IDLE the default editor for that exact file, not all .py files.

Comment: Do you know what to do when this doesn't work? For some reason I have IDLE and IDLE 3 and IDLE is the default and crashes as soon as I try to open a .py file. However, right clicking and asking to open with IDLE 3 works. So when trying to change to IDLE 3 as default, everytime I follow the procedure above and click 'Change All' it automatically reverts back to IDLE as the default i.e it doesn't actually 'Change All'. I haven't got a clue why this is happening.